# if $F$ is of finite variation, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}$ exist

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that if $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F(x)$ exist.

$$V_f[a,b]=\sup \left\{ \sum_i|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\in \varphi \}\right \}$$

where $\varphi$ is the collections of finites sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that $a\leq t_0 < t_1 <t_2 ...<t_n \leq b$.

$F$ is said to be of finite variation if $V_f(-\infty,\infty)$ is finite, namely $V_f(-\infty,\infty)<\infty$.

If $V_f(\infty,\infty)<\infty$ then both limits have to exist because otherwise, it would not even make sense to talk about $V_f(-\infty,\infty)$ being finite. However, I don't know how to prove that formally or if my reasoning is correct.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414493/limits-of-the-total-variation-when-f-infty-0

Comment: $V_f(-\infty, x]$ is an increasing function. Now show using definition of $V_f$  that $V_f-f$ is also increasing. Hence $f=V_f-(V_f-f)$ is the difference of two increasing functions.

Comment: Why does the fact the f is the difference of two increasing functions prove that the limits exist? Is it because of the finiteness of $V$ and that $V$ is defined in terms of $f$?